# getting exposed beyond app through Intent.getData() error while installing the downloaded apk file

Tags: android

I have downloaded the apk file from server and now installing it but it gives me an error: getting exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

My code is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);


        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                "/download/" + "in.sample.myapp.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

I have searched for the error and found some but unable to solve the problem. The suggestion was to use FileProvider. I did that like below just to check the log

```
Log.d("NewPath", "NewPathName is: " +(FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",outputFile)));
```

could help this out.

Please help and suggest.

Comment: Share logs for both cases

Comment: You need to replace the `Uri.fromFile()` on the `Intent` with the `Uri` returned from `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`. Just calling `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` in some arbitrary spot isn't going to fix that Exception.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks, I have replaced below code
'intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
"/download/" + "in.sample.myapp.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");'
with
  'intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",outputFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");'
err in log
'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference'

Comment: Did you set up the `FileProvider` fully? It takes more than just calling the `getUriForFile()` method. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Answer (score 7):

Your code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/FolderName/" + "yourFile.apk");
Uri data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +".provider",file);
intent.setDataAndType(data,"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

filepaths.xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm (tested on API version 24), thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use FileProvider, here is the sample code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider" ,file);
    intent.setDataAndType(data, "/*");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Also you need to include FileProvider in the manifest file 
Inside the application tag just do like this:

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Also create a xml folder in the resource directory and create a file provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <external-path name="PATH here" path=""/>
</paths>
```